# How to pass data from Ajax popup to parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, popup, window

I currently have an Ajax pop up window displayed from the main page of my application.  In this pop up I have select list and I want to pass the selected value from the pop up back to the main page when the user closes the pop up window.

I feel there is an elementary way to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: what does 'ajax popup' mean? If it's a browser window popup, it's not ajax. If it's a javascript popup being populated via an ajax request, it depends on the library/code you're using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using window.opener

http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html

Answer (score 1):

When you open a popup window via javascript (no matter if the content is via ajax or some other technique) you can easily control it.

For your problem you need **window.opener** which points back to originating document:
the clean one:

in the popup code have:

```
<body onclose="window.opener.somevar=document.getElementById('myid').value;window.opener.orsomefunction('value');">
<input id="myid"/>
</body>
```

this way, when you close it it sets a variable and/or calls a function.

you could also set the set-function on a button or directly on the input

```
<button onclick="window.opener....;window.close();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<?PHP 
$test_1 = $_GET['variable1'];
$test_2 = $_GET['variable2'];
$test_3 = $_GET['variable3'];

$test1 = "blabla1";
$test2 = "blabla2";
$test3 = "blabla3";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-1.2.4-core-yc.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     //on dom ready...
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    /* ajax replace element text */
    $('ajax-replace').addEvent('click', function(event) {
        //prevent the page from changing
        event.stop();
        //make the ajax call, replace text
        var req = new Request.HTML({
            method: 'get',
            url: $('ajax-replace').get('href'),
            data: { 'variable1' : '<?=$test1?>', 'variable2':'<?=$test2?>', 'variable3' : '<?=$test3?>' },
            //onRequest: function() { alert('Request made. Please wait...'); },
            update: $('message-here'),
            onComplete: function(response) { alert('Variable 1: <? echo $test1; ?> Variable 2: <? echo $test2; ?> Variabble 3: <? echo $test3; ?>'); $('message-here');
            }
        }).send();
    });
});

     </script>
</head>

<body>


<p>
  <a href="index.php" id="ajax-replace">Click</a> 
</p>
<div id="message-here">
<?PHP
echo $variable_1."<br>";
echo $variable_2."<br>";
echo $variable_3."<br>";
?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not appreciated at StackOverflow.